# MySQL query stucks with state "Sending Data"

Tags: mysql

I have following MySQL query which is stucked with state "Sending Data" and running from past 14 hours. Query has 3 parts. First part is a self join on table AGG_EI which fetches DISTINCT combination of uuid,cmp_id,lTypeId for the max date. Second part fetches uuid,cmp_id,lType_id,date from table CUL. First and second part are joined and stored in a temporary table. Third part selects data from temporary table and stores in CUL table.
AGG_EI table has 4.5 million records(duplicate uuid,cmp_id,lTypeId,date combination with other columns not used in query) and CUL has 0.7 million records(unique combination of uuid,cmp_id,lTypeId,date)

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_lt 
  SELECT cLType.uuid AS uuid, 
    cLType.cmp_id AS cmp_id, 
    cLType.lTypeId AS lTypeId, 
    (CASE WHEN cLType.lTypeId = eLType.lTypeId THEN eLType.lFrom 
             WHEN eLType.lFrom IS NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m%d') ELSE cLType.lFrom END) AS lFrom 
    FROM
         (
          SELECT DISTINCT d1.ei_uuid AS uuid, 
                          d1.cmp_id AS cmp_id,
                          d1.ei_type AS lTypeId,
                          d1.datedm_id AS lFrom
                          FROM AGG_EI d1 
                              LEFT OUTER JOIN AGG_EI d2 
                                              ON (d1.ei_uuid = d2.ei_uuid AND d1.cmp_id = d2.cmp_id AND d1.datedm_id < d2.datedm_id ) 
                          WHERE d2.ei_uuid IS NULL AND d2.cmp_id IS NULL
          ) AS cLType
          LEFT OUTER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT uuid AS uuid, 
                   cmp_id AS cmp_id,
                   ei_type AS lTypeId,
                   lFrom AS lFrom
                   FROM 
                       CUL
           ) AS eLType
           ON cLType.uuid = eLType.uuid AND cLType.cmp_id = eLType.cmp_id;



    INSERT INTO `CUL` (`uuid`,`cmp_id`,`ei_type`,`lFrom`)
    SELECT uuid,cmp_id,lTypeId,lFrom FROM temp_lt;
```

Why does this query gets stucked at state "sending data"

Explain :

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 2420567 
1   PRIMARY <derived3>  ALL                 687777  
3   DERIVED CUL index       comp_uuid   468     688032  Using index
2   DERIVED d1  index       datedm_id_UNIQUE    492     4046120 Using index; Using temporary
2   DERIVED d2  ref datedm_id_UNIQUE,agg_ei_comdm_fk_idx,agg_ei_datedm_fk_idx,comp_uuid comp_uuid   460 ol.d1.com_id,ol.d1.ei_uuid  1   Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

Comment: Query to create temporary table gets stuck

Answer (score 0):

Use DESCRIBE to explain your query and see where it slows down.Sometimes sending data means that Mysql  has data stored on the disk  which is yet to read.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed subquery for CUL and query got executed in 150s...not sure what is the reason

```
     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_lt 
     SELECT cLType.uuid AS uuid, 
cLType.cmp_id AS cmp_id, 
cLType.lTypeId AS lTypeId, 
(CASE WHEN cLType.lTypeId = eLType.lTypeId THEN eLType.lFrom 
         WHEN eLType.lFrom IS NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m%d') ELSE cLType.lFrom END) AS lFrom 
FROM
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT d1.ei_uuid AS uuid, 
                      d1.cmp_id AS cmp_id,
                      d1.ei_type AS lTypeId,
                      d1.datedm_id AS lFrom
                      FROM AGG_EI d1 
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN AGG_EI d2 
                                          ON (d1.ei_uuid = d2.ei_uuid AND d1.cmp_id = d2.cmp_id AND d1.datedm_id < d2.datedm_id ) 
                      WHERE d2.ei_uuid IS NULL AND d2.cmp_id IS NULL
      ) AS cLType
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT uuid AS uuid, 
               cmp_id AS cmp_id,
               ei_type AS lTypeId,
               lFrom AS lFrom
               FROM 
                   CUL
       ) AS eLType
       ON cLType.uuid = eLType.uuid AND cLType.cmp_id = eLType.cmp_id;



INSERT INTO `CUL` (`uuid`,`cmp_id`,`ei_type`,`lFrom`)
SELECT uuid,cmp_id,lTypeId,lFrom FROM temp_lt;
```

EXPLAIN :
New approach

```
    1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 2420567 
1   PRIMARY eLType  eq_ref  PRIMARY,uuid_cmp_id,comp_fk_idx,comp_uuid   PRIMARY 460 cLType.uuid,cLType.cmpId    1   
2   DERIVED d1  index       datedm_id_UNIQUE    492     4046120 Using index; Using temporary
2   DERIVED d2  ref datedm_id_UNIQUE,agg_ei_comdm_fk_idx,agg_ei_datedm_fk_idx,comp_uuid comp_uuid   460 ol.d1.comp_id,ol.d1.ei_uuid 1   Using where; Using index; Not exists
```